# Can you help me to resolve the error I am getting after running Stringtie prepDE.py?

Tags: python

When I run prepDE.py job exit with the following error. I am using StringTie/2.1.4 with Python/2.7.18.
Following is the command I was running (inside ADA cluster)

```
#Loading New modules

module load StringTie/2.1.4-GCC-9.3.0
module load Python/2.7.18-GCCcore-9.3.0

#converting data to DESEQ2 compatible format

prepDE.py
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/sw/eb/software/StringTie/2.1.4-GCC-9.3.0/bin/prepDE.py", line 58, in
> samples = [(i,glob.iglob(os.path.join(opts.input,i,"*.gtf")).next())
> for i in next(os.walk(opts.input))[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fylD3.jpg) if re.search(opts.pattern,i)]
> StopIteration

I have a directory structure as follows [Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fylD3.jpg)

```
├── ballgown
│   ├── PVX_2d_1
│   │   ├── e2t.ctab
│   │   ├── e_data.ctab
│   │   ├── i2t.ctab
│   │   ├── i_data.ctab
│   │   ├── PVX_2d_1.gtf
│   │   └── t_data.ctab
│   ├── PVX_2d_2
│   │   ├── e2t.ctab
│   │   ├── e_data.ctab
│   │   ├── i2t.ctab
│   │   ├── i_data.ctab
│   │   ├── PVX_2d_2.gtf
│   │   └── t_data.ctab
│   ├── PVX_2d_3
│   │   ├── e2t.ctab
│   │   ├── e_data.ctab
│   │   ├── i2t.ctab
│   │   ├── i_data.ctab
│   │   ├── PVX_2d_3.gtf
│   │   └── t_data.ctab
```

Can you help me in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also share the command line you're using. The exception smells like the application is not finding files where it expects to.

Comment: Just updated the post. I was following the instructions given here http://ccb.jhu.edu/software/stringtie/index.shtml?t=manual#deseq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an educated guess based on the error and the [documentation linked](http://ccb.jhu.edu/software/stringtie/index.shtml?t=manual#deseq):

> -i INPUT, --input=INPUT, --in=INPUT
> – a folder containing all sample sub-directories, or a text file with sample ID and path to its GTF file on each line [default: . ]

Try invoking the script with

```
prepDE.py -i ballgown
```

since the data subfolders are in a `ballgown` folder.